# Await doesn't actually wait for an async function to complete

Tags: node.js, async-await, redis

I'm starting to use Redis for caching in my NodeJS app. Unlike all the tutorials that can be found on the internet (for example this one: https://medium.com/geekculture/fasten-your-node-js-application-with-a-powerful-caching-mechanism-using-redis-fd76b8aa482f), I don't send the `res` just after calling the "cache" function. My "cache" function is a middleware returning a value if found.

Here is where the function is called:

```
const { requestLDAP } = require('../utils/ldap')
router.get('/:mode/:type/:code', async (req, res) => {

  (...)

  const resultLDAP = await requestLDAP(
    type, params
  );
  console.log('---');
  console.log(resultLDAP);
  console.log('---');
```

And here is the part of the LDAP module:

```
async function requestLDAP(type, params) {
    const key = JSON.stringify({type,params});
    // checking the cache
    await clientRedis.get(key, async (err, response) => {
      if (response) {
        console.log("[CACHE]");
        return {
          ok: true,
          contenu: JSON.parse(response),
        };
      } else {
        const simulated = Array.from({ length: 5 }, () => {
          let r = { type: type.slice(0, -1) };
          params.forEach((k) => {
            r[k] = `${cle}_${Math.floor(100*Math.random(100))}`;
          });
          return r;
        });
        console.log("[API]");
        await clientRedis.setex(cle, 10, JSON.stringify(simulated));
        console.log('[SAVED]');
        return {
          ok: true,
          contenu: simulated,
        };
      (...)
```

I don't write all the rest, which is basically all the actual LDAP call.

My problem is that the script doesn't seem to wait for the "await" to complete. Here is what I have in the console:

```
---
undefined
---
---
undefined
---
[CACHE]
[CACHE]
```

What am I missing here?
If I write `console.log(response)` I have the correct response, but once again AFTER expected.

[EDIT]
After helpful comments, here is how I wrote the function:

```
let finalResponse = await clientRedis.get(cle, async (err, response) => {
  if (response) {
    console.log("[CACHE]");
    return response;
  } else {
    (...)
return {
  ok: true,
  contenu: finalResponse,
};
```

but `finalResponse` is a boolean, it doesn't return the real `response`.

Comment: You are not returning anything from your requestLDAP function.

Comment: It probably should be `return await clientRedis.get()`, since you now just return in the callback to it

Comment: You are using the Redis library incorrectly, you are mixing callbacks with async/await.

Comment: You need to "promisify" that `clientRedis.get` call. Here is a [good resource](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/write-your-own-promisify-function-from-scratch/) explaining how to do it.

Comment: I edited my answer, the "async" part is good, the content of the response very strange, though...

Comment: @tromgy you were right. Here is what I used, it works like a charm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-redis

Comment: @tromgy, in addition to his comment. I would like to add that when you use async/await use try/catch with it and never use callbacks with it. You can convert CB to promises using `util.promisify`. Also, when you use the async function it does wrap your response in a promise, but you need to return something from the function to get the values.

Answer (score 1):

As they said before, requestLDAP function returns nothing, not an actual Promise that you can wait for.

You need that requestLDAP returns a Promise because you are waiting for the result of clientRedis that you don't know when will you have it.

When you have it, you have to resolve or reject the Promise mentioned. A return here is not a return for requestLDAP, but for the caller of the callback.

Try packing and returning a promise like this:

```
async function requestLDAP(type, params) {
  return new Promise( async (resolve,reject) => { // --> Promisify the asynchronous response
    const key = JSON.stringify({type,params});
    // checking the cache
    await clientRedis.get(key, async (err, response) => {
      if(err) reject('Something ugly happened here'); // --> Give a result for the promise in the future
      if (response) {
        console.log("[CACHE]");
        resolve( { // --> Give a result for the promise in the future
          ok: true,
          contenu: JSON.parse(response),
        } );
      } else {
        const simulated = Array.from({ length: 5 }, () => {
          let r = { type: type.slice(0, -1) };
          params.forEach((k) => {
            r[k] = `${cle}_${Math.floor(100*Math.random(100))}`;
          });
          return r;
        });
        console.log("[API]");
        await clientRedis.setex(cle, 10, JSON.stringify(simulated));
        console.log('[SAVED]');
        resolve( { // --> Give a result for the promise in the future
          ok: true,
          contenu: simulated,
        } );
      (...)
      }
    });
  }
};
```